# How to Return 'Instance of Document Reference' to Flutter from Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which contains, among other things, these three lines:

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();
db.doc(path);
```

I use these three lines extensively, across the function to interact with firestore. They even save document references as such in firestore. However, I can't get them to return a document reference to the Flutter frontend.

The variable, let's call it `yourReference`, is saved to firestore in one line, shows as a `documentReference`, and in the very next line is returned to the Flutter frontend like this:

```
response.json({
      referenceItem: yourReference,
    });
```

And yet the frontend does not get an instance of document reference, but a map with document reference related keys! I.e. `{_path:..., _firestore:...}`, etc. Please note that the Flutter frontend is making a post request to the cloud function, and not using the cloud-functions library for Flutter.

Comment: Are you actually just trying to return a document reference to the client, or are you trying to return actual document data? It's not clear from what you have now.  Please edit the question to show the entire code of the function, as well as the Flutter code that you use to call it.  If your code doesn't work or has errors, you should describe exactly what's not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

A `DocumentReference` is just a reference to a document in the database. In your first snippet, the reference is not much more than `path`. So if you want to return the path to a document to the Flutter user, you should return the `path` and not the `DocumentReference`.

If you want to return the actual contents of the document to the user, you'll first need to read that document with something like:

```
let doc = await db.doc(path).get();
console.log(doc.data());
```

The `doc.data()` in this snippet is the data from the document, which you'll then want to return to the Flutter app. How to do that depends on the [Cloud Function type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) you're using, but with a HTTPS function it'd be something like.

```
res.write(doc.data());
```

Comment: Thanks, Puf! I'll just return the path as a string then! :)